# Dataframe to json in layers

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
school_id  city  id    name   batch   roll_no  age 
   xx       ax    1    abc     a1      100     13
   xx       ax    1    dsf     a2      200     45
   xx       ax    2    fas     a1      400     23
```

i have to convert it into  multi layered json format:
such that it gives a message at the top as key.
school_id, and city are same in all the rows so they are at the top level, and 
then nesting by id's.
My result should look something like this,  or even better by nesting on **id** column too

```
{
  "message": "The school Table.",
  "school_id": "xx",
  "city": "ax",
  "ids": [
    {
     "id" : 1,
     "name" : "abc",
     "batch" : "a1",
     "roll_no" : 100,
     "age" : 13
     },
     {
     "id" : 1,
     "name" : "abc",
     "batch" : "a1",
     "roll_no" : 100,
     "age" : 13
      },
    {
     "id" : 1,
     "name" : "dsf",
     "batch" : "a2",
     "roll_no" : 200,
     "age" : 45
      },
    {
     "id" : 2,
     "name" : "fas",
     "batch" : "a1",
     "roll_no" : 400,
     "age" : 23
      }
       ]
}
```

Comment: `"message": "The school Table."` as added to json manually?

Comment: @jezrael yes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add new column `message` and then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with custom function for `dict` by [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html), [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and last convert to `json` by [`to_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html):

```
print (df)
  school_id city  id  name batch  roll_no  age
0        xx   ax   1   abc    a1      100   13
1        xx   ax   1   dsf    a2      200   45
2        xy   ay   2   fas    a1      400   23
3        xy   ay   3  fas1   a11      500   33

j = (df.assign(message='The school Table.')
       .groupby(['message','school_id','city'])['id','name','batch','roll_no','age']
       .apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('r'))
       .reset_index(name='ids')
       .to_json(orient='records')
        )
print (j)

[{"message":"The school Table.",
  "school_id":"xx",
  "city":"ax",
  "ids":[{"roll_no":100,"batch":"a1","age":13,"name":"abc","id":1},
         {"roll_no":200,"batch":"a2","age":45,"name":"dsf","id":1}]},
  {"message":"The school Table.",
   "school_id":"xy",
   "city":"ay",
   "ids":[{"roll_no":400,"batch":"a1","age":23,"name":"fas","id":2},
          {"roll_no":500,"batch":"a11","age":33,"name":"fas1","id":3}]}]
```

Comment: Damn you are so fast!

Comment: @AntonvBR Indeed he is! :)

Comment: And he keeps improving the solution :). Cannot give more than 1 upvote though

Comment: @AntonvBR - Thank you.

Comment: @jezrael I am trying your code for a dataset, your previous solution, (doing groupby and then assigning new column d['message'] was working fine, but now that you're using df.assign, i am not able to see "message" in my result json

Comment: Because you forget add `message` to `groupby`, sorry, I dont mentioned it.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want to use a groupby:

```
import json

outputs = []
ids = ["school_id","city"]

for ind,df in df.groupby(ids):
    output = dict(zip(ids,ind),
                  message="School Table",
                  ids=df.drop(ids,axis=1).to_dict('r'))
    outputs.append(output)

print(json.dumps(outputs[0],indent=2))
```

Outputs:

```
{
  "city": "ax",
  "message": "School Table",
  "ids": [
    {
      "roll_no": 100,
      "id": 1,
      "age": 13,
      "batch": "a1",
      "name": "abc"
    },
    {
      "roll_no": 200,
      "id": 1,
      "age": 45,
      "batch": "a2",
      "name": "dsf"
    },
    {
      "roll_no": 400,
      "id": 2,
      "age": 23,
      "batch": "a1",
      "name": "fas"
    }
  ],
  "school_id": "xx"
}
```